# How to make a snap package from a python project without setup.py?

Tags: python, snap, packaging

Suppose,

1. there is only one `program.py`,
   or 2. there are a few files and an `init.py` executes the program.

How to turn it into a snap package?
[This guide](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/snap-a-python-application#0) assumes there is a `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, create a `setup.py` because it is the regular workflow. Only if you have real issue that prevents you from doing so.

Most of the packagers are dealing with snapcraft as black-box, They are just its users. So please don't expect easy shortcuts.